# Database management php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I started learning Php scripting today only,i want to create an auction website for my college. I have a bid table having the following columns:

- Userid
- Itemid
- Bidamount

When a user logs in ,and goes to "Items.php" page and when he will click on the bid option on an item (each item has an `itemid`)he will be redirected to "bid.php" page.
My doubt is: I will get the useid by `$_SESSION['userid']`, will i similarly also get the 
itemid automatically by the `$_SESSION['itemid']`, if not how do i pass the itemid to the bid.php page.

Comment: you get this `$_SESSION['userid']` not by PHP. do you use some framework or tutorial code etc.?

Comment: Your question title "*Database management php mysql*" doesn't suit the contents of the question.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to to use an href tag to pass a variable to your bid.php and fetch it using get.

i.e 
        `<a href ="bid.php?id=1">Bid now!</a>`

in your bid.php

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you would create a from and use POST or GET information that is passed by the form. you would not get this from session

here's a tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: thanks, i dont have a form in the item.php  page,is there any other way other than form ,that will pass the itemid of the item whose bid option is clicked,to the bid.php page..thanks

Comment: "*you would create a **from***". Must be **form**. Isn't it?

Comment: a form is not necessary for this functionality, you can just use an href tag.

Comment: how are you sending the data then? what link are you using? You could also use a url variable when you are generating a link.

Comment: yes a url variable is another way to approach this functionality. you can also add some ajax

Comment: how to generate this variable url ?if it is created then the problem is solved..like for every item's bid option i want the url to have itemid as suggested by Mr.Reb Tuble